# problem with two controls having the same datasource

Tags: winforms

I am building a winforms application, i have two comboboxes which have the same datasource, the datasource is a DataTable. Now, when I select a value in one comboBox, the value of another comboBox is changed too. Is there a way make it change without affecting the other?

Comment: Hi Terry, if you remove the code tag from your question, it will be simpler to read. :)

Answer (score 1):

In that type of scenario, you can create two different binding sources, one bound to each of your combo boxes. If you set the `DataSource` property of each of the binding data sources to your `DataTable`, then your combo boxes will work independently, while still showing the same data.

The initialisation would be something like:

```
// Initialization of the binding sources(assuming dataTable is a populated DataTable)
bindingSource.DataSource = dataTable;
bindingSource2.DataSource = dataTable;
```

Comment: Nope. Even with two BindingSources, WinForms still synchronizes the controls.

Answer (score 1):

The WinForms binding system is detecting that both comboboxes are hooked up to the same DataSource and is (helpfully) syncing changes across the two.

To avoid this you need to ensure each combobox has a distinct DataSource.

One way is to use the appropriate non-visual component from the Toolbox ([BindingSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.aspx)).

Another, if you're setting up your bindings with code, is to use [BindingList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132679.aspx). Note that there is one trap with BindingList - it *can* act as a *wrapper*:

> [The] BindingList constructor creates a WRAPPER collection around the original list. It doesn't create a new list containing the same elements. (I've never seen this documented, but have verified with Reflector).
>   -- http://www.nichesoftware.co.nz/blog/200809/databinding-lists

Instead of:

```
editDebitAccount.DataSource = accountsList;
editCreditAccount.DataSource = accountsList;
```

use this:

```
editDebitAccount.DataSource = new BindingList(accountsList);
editCreditAccount.DataSource = new BindingList(accountsList);
```

Comment: >>The WinForms binding system is detecting that both comboboxes are hooked up to the same DataSource and is (helpfully) syncing changes across the two.<< I see, but why? It does not make sense since the combobox contain the selected item, not the datasource.

Comment: It might be suprising, but it's the way it works. When two comboboxes have the same DataSource set, they end up sharing the same [CurrencyManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.currencymanager.aspx). The CurrencyManager specifies the `Current` position in the list, and both comboboxes sync with that.